# Android TCP ServerSocket.accept() blocking

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I've been working on a simple Android TCP Server, so I can connect from a TCP Client and pass data back and forth.

I am encountering an weird problem, my android phone creates the TCP Socket, and I am able to connect to it via Hercules utility (A TCP client). The connection goes through, however the program is still blocking at the ServerSocket.accept() method.

Could anyone shed some light on this issue? Here is my java function.

```
    public void TcpServer()
{
    try
    {
        Socket s = null;
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        System.out.println("TCP Server Starting");
        ss = new ServerSocket(27015);

            s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("New connection! Yay");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String incomingMsg = input.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + incomingMsg);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I am running this on a Samsung Galaxy S4. I downloaded the application TCP Socket from the App store and it worked fine.

Comment: Define "the connection goes through". The method is blocking, not hanging. And never ignore an IOException. You may have got one here.

Comment: `readline()` also blocks until input is received.